# How do you make groups for a variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have the following code:

```
base_99 <- ggplot(df, aes(dates, y, colour = text$likes_count)) + geom_point() + 
  labs(y ='Número de palabras por tweet', x='Años', color = 'Número de likes por tweet')
```

which gives me the following scatterplot:
[image]

I want to have groups of the color legend. For example: 0:30, 31-61, 62:91, 92:121
How can I do that in ggplot?
Thank you

Comment: It's best if you can provide some of your data, via `dput(head(df))`. You can also check out https://r-charts.com/correlation/scatter-plot-group-ggplot2/

Comment: Can you say more specifically what you mean by "I want to have groups of the color legend"? Do you want all the labels, but arranged in groups? Or perhaps new groupings so you only need to use 4 colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your *likes counts* are stored as a character vector instead of a integer-vector.

I think it will work (or at least give you a useful legend, but perhaps different from what you considered) if you convert `$text$likes_count` to integers.

Without data, I can't test if it gives you the results you want, but try

```r
base_99 <- ggplot(df, aes(dates, y, colour = as.integer(text$likes_count))) + geom_point() + 
  labs(y ='Número de palabras por tweet', x='Años', color = 'Número de likes por tweet')
```

You can also use [`cut`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut) to break the numbers into a series of ranges.

Again, I can't test, but try:

```r
base_99 <- ggplot(
    df, aes(dates, y, colour = cut(as.integer(text$likes_count), 10))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(y ='Número de palabras por tweet', x='Años', color = 'Número de likes por tweet')
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you very much